# How to determine the target device programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, device, target, galaxy

I would like to programmatically determine (on the Android platform), if the target device is a phone or a tablet.
Is there a way to do this? 
I tried using Density Metrics to determine the resolution and used resources (images and layouts) accordingly but, it did not turn out well. There are differences when I launch the app on a phone (Droid X) and a tablet (Samsung Galaxy 10.1).

Please advise.

Comment: What type of differences do you see? Look at this and realize just design for the display size and the hardware you need: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d6323d81f226f93f

Comment: Thank you for the reference, James.
The differences were artifacts in rendering. The objects wouldn't render at the same position when testing on the phone as compared to the tablet.

Comment: So is the problem now solved?

Comment: I am experimenting a bit by adding more resources according to the screen size and density. For now, one of the modules is working using the alternative resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect device is Android phone or Android tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
private boolean isTabletDevice() {

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // honeycomb
    // test screen size, use reflection because isLayoutSizeAtLeast is only available since 11
    Configuration con = getResources().getConfiguration();
    try {
        Method mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast = con.getClass().getMethod("isLayoutSizeAtLeast", int.class);
        Boolean r = (Boolean) mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast.invoke(con, 0x00000004); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
        return r;
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Link: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-detect-tablet-device

Comment: this is incorrect, for ICS now works both on tablets and phones, and it's SDK is >=11.

Comment: Vlad, after check if the version is >= 11, check if the layout size is XLARGE

Answer (score 0):

As James has already mentioned, You can determine screen size programatically and use a threshold Number to differrentiate between your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Aracem's answer, I updated the snippet with normal tablet check for 3.2 or higher (sw600dp):

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) { // Honeycomb 3.2
            Configuration con = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
            Field fSmallestScreenWidthDp = con.getClass().getDeclaredField("smallestScreenWidthDp");
            return fSmallestScreenWidthDp.getInt(con) >= 600;
        } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) { // Honeycomb 3.0
            Configuration con = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
            Method mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast = con.getClass().getMethod("isLayoutSizeAtLeast", int.class);
            Boolean r = (Boolean) mIsLayoutSizeAtLeast.invoke(con, 0x00000004); // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
            return r;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;

}
```