# Is there a system property to know whether the device is mobile or tablet or desktop in android?

Tags: java, android

Hi is there a system propert to know on which device the JVM is running. It is to know whether it is a mobile or tablet in android?

Comment: also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet

Comment: sorry. I found the answer on other post that u specified. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use DisplayMetric properties (width, height), to find if the device is tab/mobile.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;

if (SharedCode.width > 1023 || SharedCode.height > 1023){
//code for big screen (like tablet)
}else{
//code for small screen (like smartphone)
}
```