# Detecting whether the device is a phone or a tablet when installing my app

Tags: android

I only want my app installed on a tablet and attempts to install it on a phone should be blocked.  How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android/9590506#9590506

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832368/tablet-or-phone-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your manifest :

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```