# Correctly detect Android device type

Tags: android

Is there any a way to precisely detect the device type (phone, tablet, watch, TV, auto, PC)?

Right now, I found a way to detect if the app is running on a car (`uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR`), on a TV (`uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION`), or on a watch (`uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH`). 
Is it correct? Does a phone connected to a car appears as a phone or as "Android Auto"?

To differentiate between a phone, tablet or computer I can check for the minimum screen size (600dp to qualify as tablet or laptop for example).

The problem now is to differentiate between a tablet and a laptop. Have you got any idea?

PS: I'm not asking this to make a responsive UI, it's a question related to the device management for an account

Answer (score 14):

You can detect using this code application running on large screen or not.

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
  }
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet) would be also helpful to you.

Get Width of screen  and check that with this break-points.

/* Tablet (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

```
 min-device-width : 768px
 max-device-width : 1024px
```

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

```
min-width : 1224px
```

Comment: How to differentiate between a tablet and a computer? They both have a large screen

Comment: There are tablets with more pixels than laptops. And anyhow, the screen size isn't what differentiate a tablet from a laptop

Comment: As has been pointed out before, pixel count is not a reliable way of determining device type as many newly released phones have sizes far exceeding what a normal tablet used to have just a few years ago.

Answer (score 5):

> To differentiate between a phone and a tablet or computer I can check for the minimum screen size (600dp to qualify as talet or laptop for example).

There is a better way to do that and it's using values. For example, if you have 2 type of devices (say phone and tablet), create two folder for values too. Then for values folder add this:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarge">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and in your values-large folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarge">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in your activity:

```
boolean isLarge = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLarge);
if (isLarge) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Using this, you can do same thing for phone, sw-600dp, sw-720dp and etc. I'm not sure if you can use this for TV and etc, but I think it worth to try.

Comment: How to differentiate between a tablet and a computer? They both have a large screen

Answer (score 5):

please refer this link,

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali

here below i put the code for checking Tablet or android TV, please check, it will works

> for tablet

```
private boolean checkIsTablet() {
   boolean isTablet;
   Display display = ((Activity)   this.mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   display.getMetrics(metrics);

  float widthInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
  float heightInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi;
  double diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(widthInches, 2) + Math.pow(heightInches, 2));
  if (diagonalInches >= 7.0) {
    isTablet = true;
  }

return isTablet;
}
```

or

```
public static boolean checkIsTablet(Context ctx){    
return (ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE; 
}
```

> for TV

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private boolean checkIsTelevision() {
  boolean isAndroidTV;
  int uiMode = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode;
  if ((uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_MASK) == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
    isAndroidTV = true;
}
```

It will works, enjoy...

Comment: How to differentiate from a tablet and a laptop? A big screen doesn't make any device a tablet

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the physical screen size is large (=tablet or laptop-like device):

```
private static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {
    boolean device_large = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) ==
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);

    if (device_large) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
            AppInstance.getLogger().logD("DeviceHelper","IsTabletDevice-True");
            return true;
        }
    }
    AppInstance.getLogger().logD("DeviceHelper","IsTabletDevice-False");
    return false;
}
```

Check whether the app is running in the Android SDK emulator:

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
        || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
        || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
        || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
        || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
        || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
```

}

Check whether the device is an Android TV:

```
    public static final String TAG = "DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck";

    UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
    if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device")
}
```

Comment: How to differentiate from a tablet and a laptop? A big screen doesn't make any device a tablet

Answer (score 1):

Use following static methods for getting device name,id, height, and width. For more detail visit at this [link](https://github.com/multidots/android-app-common-tasks). Project includes all common feature that basic android application want.

```
     public static String getDeviceName() {
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
            return capitalize(model);
        } else {
            return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
        }
    }

    public static String getDeviceID(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }

    public static int getDeviceHeight(Context mContext) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    }

    public static int getDeviceWidth(Context mContext) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        return displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: how to get the device type (i.e. phone, tablet, tv, car, watch or computer)?

Answer (score 0):

Check this class. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER
String model = Build.MODEL
```

You can know if its phone, tab or TV from Build.MODEL

Comment: Unfortunately this method isn't applicable in this context, since I'd need to associate every device model with it's type manually. I need a method that works today and will work tomorrow... I guess that it doesn't exists :(