# Android screen orientation in layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

So I have such problem I want to set layout default orientation in AndroidManifest.xml as landscape, but have different orientation for some layouts as portrait, but when I add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` it doesn't override manifest configuration is there any work around? Main idea is to have tablets layout forced landscape and phone layout forced portrait.

Here is an example of the same app for tablet and phone notice how layout orientation as landscape is forced for tablets and it doesn't rotate when device is rotated. And for phone is locked in portrait orientation and it doesn't rotate when device is rotated
[image]

Comment: Yea I know, but it has to be done like this :) I updated my question, main Idea is to have different orientations for tablets and phones

Comment: explaining what you are trying to accomplish with a picture would be better for understanding your problem.

Comment: you can android:screenOrientation on a single activity, not in the "application" tag. If you want to define both landscape and portait configuration you should follow this page of the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: I tried adding only for layout but then it doesn't force it. When I rotate the device it switches orientation

Comment: first you identify app install in tablet or mobile device. follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet and then you paste code of orientation for tablet. @kosas

Comment: this is promising one

Comment: gonna wait for more answers would be cool to set it through layout only

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setRequestedOrientation` but landscape case the phone rotation must be enabled:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Calculate the screen size considering that tablet are more than 6.9" (I used this at my application) :

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
 double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
 double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
 double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
```

Comment: problem with this is that I can't tell which device is in use

Comment: because I need landscape for tablets only and portrait for phones only

Comment: I updated my answer with self experienced situation, I mean using 6.9 to differ between tablet and phone

Comment: screenInches <= 6.5 then its a phone else Tablet