# How to find Tablet or Phone in Android , Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

My case is that the logic is same for both Phone and Tablet. But there is slight difference in the layout. And I tried with the following code

```
public static boolean findoutDeviceType(Context context) 
    {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                       Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)>= 
                           Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
    }
```

Samsung Tab 10" has the resolution of 1280 * 800 and S3 has the resolution of 1270 * 720.  And this code returns the Size as XLarge for both the Tab and Phone as its criteria for checking is > 960 * 720.

I have tested inserting the respective UI in the layout folder in Res as Layout, Layout-Large and Layout-xLarge . But this didn't effect in anyway. while checking it took the UI from the Layout folder.

Anyway even though I place the UI in the different layout folders, I have to check them in the class file to set the respective ContentView.

Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: Check: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251131/how-to-determine-the-target-device-programmatically-in-android), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884517/how-to-know-whether-its-a-tablet-or-phone-in-android-programmatically), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330363/how-to-detect-device-is-android-phone-or-android-tablet), [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-detect-tablet-device)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
    public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }
```

It will return true if you are using a tablet. It has been checked on Samsung Galaxy Tab 7" and Samsung Galaxy S3.

Comment: checking on two devices _IS NOT_ a good enough check. Be very wary of this method as it is not reliable.

Comment: basing yourself on device dimension is the worst idea possible to determine a device. I don't know why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 64):

This subject is discussed in the Android Training:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali

[**Here is implementation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284/1450401),

Credit goes to [**ol_v_er**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384483/ol-v-er) for this simple and easy approach.

**Some additional Information**

You have now flag indicate whether your application is running on phone or tablet.

I have created two packages to handle UI and it's functionality,

```
com.phone
com.tablet
```

And you redirect control to your needed package

```
boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
if (tabletSize) {
    // do something
    //Start activity for tablet
} else {
    // do something else
    //Start activity for phone     
}
```

[**Refer**](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)

**Note** :I think for both 10 inch and 7 inch screen app take resources from `res/values-sw600dp/` . But To be more specific  I think for 10 inch tablet screen we can use `res/values-sw720dp/`

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Comment: You should cite your source when you copy-paste: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9308284

Answer (score 3):

For example, you could set some res-values folder:

res/values-xlarge
res/values-large
res/values-sw600dp

etc. Then You could declare a boolean for each one:

```
    <resources>
<bool name="isXLarge">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

or

```
    <resources>
<bool name="isLarge">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

you can get the value by

```
   boolean xlargeValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isXlarge);
   boolean largevalue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLarge);
   boolean tabletValue = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.sw620dp):
```

Answer (score 3):

## Try this code your app is working device phone or tablet easy to fine call the method oncreate()  inside

isTabletDevice(activity)

```
private static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {

    boolean device_large = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
          Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    if (device_large) {
        //Tablet
        if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT){              
            return true;
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM){
            return true;    
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV){
            return true;    
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH){
            return true;    
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280){
            return true;    
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
            return true;
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400) {
            return true;
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH) {
            return true;
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560) {
            return true;
        }else if(metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH) {
            return true;
        }            
    }else{
        //Mobile
         } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but this might help someone.
If you want to find out if device is tablet (screen lager than 7"), or phone, you can use this util method:

Kotlin

```
fun isTablet(): Boolean {
    return App.instance.resources.configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600
}
```

Java

```
public static Boolean isTablet(){
    return App.instance.resources.configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600
}
```

App.instance is aplication instance.

Comment: These values do not represent the physical size of the device. In multi-window mode, they will become smaller.

Comment: The Java code is mis-quoted. To start with, it is not Java code. To the person who posted it: if you want share any code which you didn't write, please understand it thoroughly, before rushing it out. I also agree with " 
Miloš Černilovský' comment: these values do not represent the physical size. The solution is definitely wrong in multi-window mode

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean isTablet() { 
try { 
    // Compute screen size 
 Context context = this;
    DisplayMetrics dm = 
 context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
    float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi; 
    float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi; 
    double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + 
                            Math.pow(screenHeight, 2)); 
    // Tablet devices have a screen size greater than 6 
      inches 
    return size >= 6; 
  } catch(Throwable t) { 
    Log.e("Failed to compute screen size", t.toString()); 
    return false; 
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You can get the screen inches, On the basis of size you can get the tablet or android device

```
 String inputSystem;
    inputSystem = android.os.Build.ID;
    Log.d("hai",inputSystem);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
    int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
    Log.d("hai",width+"");
    Log.d("hai",height+"");
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi,2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
    Log.d("hai","Screen inches : " + screenInches+"");
```

Comment: Yes but if there are only these two devices ( Say samsung S3 and Samsung 10" Tablet) we can compare , but how do i do for other device also ....... there are various resolution sizes for various devices . S4 device screen is even more bigger .

Comment: but android device size is not like tablet size, so you can only get this one is android mobile device or tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Use different resource files rather than trying to determine it programmatically. This will be enough for the majority of cases and is what the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) recommends.

[image]

See my fuller answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646301/3681880).

Answer (score 0):

All other questions use resource qualifiers and methods, which do not represent the PHYSICAL size of the device, but the AVAILABLE screen size. For example, in the multi-window mode, the system will get resources from the "values" folder instead of "values-large", because the available screen size for the app became smaller. To determine, whether the physical device is a tablet or phone, use the following method (I use `640x480dp` as the minimum size for a tablet, which is the definition of `large` devices, feel free to change these constants):

```
fun isTablet(context: Context): Boolean {
    val outSize = Point()
    val windowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(outSize)
    outSize.x = pxToDp(windowManager, outSize.x)
    outSize.y = pxToDp(windowManager, outSize.y)
    val shorterSideDp: Int
    val longerSideDp: Int
    if (outSize.x > outSize.y) {
        shorterSideDp = outSize.y
        longerSideDp = outSize.x
    } else {
        shorterSideDp = outSize.x
        longerSideDp = outSize.y
    }
    return shorterSideDp > 480 && longerSideDp > 640
}
```

Function for converting PX to DP:

```
@Dimension(unit = Dimension.DP)
fun pxToDp(windowManager: WindowManager, @Dimension(unit = Dimension.PX) px: Int): Int {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics)
    return (px / displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() * DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT).roundToInt()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working perfectly well in my app:

```
private boolean isPhoneDevice(){

    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);

}
```

Comment: This only checks if the device can work as a telephone. Definition: "The device has a telephony radio with data communication support.". Some tablets and phones with really big screns will return true on this.