# How do I stop Android tablet phone-app launch?

Tags: android

Whenever I swipe my Android tablet to launch it, the phone app fires up. How do I stop the phone app? I never use it.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for [android.se], a similar site with similar structure, but a focus on Android usage and customization.

Answer (score 0):

according to me you can create an extra screen where you check the device's type (mobile, tablet, etc).

- If the user's device is not a tablet you can call an intent to your desired first screen.
- Else use the intent for exiting the application and removing it from recent.

Links for your reference -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784317/12060353

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).